# Multiplication of a number with a table

Tags: r, vector

I have inserted a table from text in R with the command read.table, but I want to multiply the prices in one of its rows with some number. I have tried to do the following:

```
x=matrx(, nrow=184,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:184){x[i]=c[2,i+1]*z}
```

where c is a table of 3 columns and 185 rows and z is a number, say 10. I can not make this multiplication, why is this? 
Also, should I insert the tables as matrices or it is the same? If no, is there a way to convert them somehow or insert them with some other command instead of read.table?

Comment: Don't loop, just multiply as is. e.g., `c * z` or such (I'm not quite certain what's your desired output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, a matrix is just a vector of numbers that has dimensions.  The `matrix` function adds the dimensions to the vector.  The values in the vector fill each column, in order, in the matrix.  Consider:

```
> x = 5:16
> x
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

> xMatrix = matrix(x, nrow = 4)
> xMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    9   13
[2,]    6   10   14
[3,]    7   11   15
[4,]    8   12   16
```

Now, values in the vector and the matrix can be accessed using indices:

```
> x[10:11]
[1] 14 15
> xMatrix[2:3,3]
[1] 14 15
```

Interestingly, the matrix is still a vector (it's just a vector with dimensions), and can be treated as such:

```
> xMatrix[10:11]
[1] 14 15
```

Multiplication in R is vectorized.  If you multiply two vectors together, the first value in each vector is multiplied together, the second values in each vector is multiplied together, etc.  So:

```
> x*x
 [1]  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256
```

If one vector is shorter than the other, the short vector is "recycled:"

```
> x * 1:2
 [1]  5 12  7 16  9 20 11 24 13 28 15 32
```

If you use a single value (a vector of length = 1), then that value is recycled:

```
> x * 10
 [1]  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160
```

So, putting it all together, you can multiply each value in an entire matrix by a constant simply by using the code:

```
> xMatrix * 2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   18   26
[2,]   12   20   28
[3,]   14   22   30
[4,]   16   24   32
```

If you want to multiply only one row of a vector by a value, and update the contents of the vector, use:

```
xMatrix[2,] = xMatrix[2,] * 10
```

to update the second row.  Result:

```
> xMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   50    9   13
[2,]  600  100  140
[3,]   70   11   15
[4,]   80   12   16
```